# pushing application logs on azure app services to logstash

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, logging, logstash

I'm looking for suggestions on pushing logs for applications hosted on Azure app services (both on windows and linux app service plans) to a hosted logstash instance.

With some research I've established that for applications hosted on windows app service plans, filebeat could be setup as a web job on the same app service and have it push application logs to logstash, but no similar solution for applications hosted on linux app service plans.

Applications needed to be monitored are a mix; .NET4.x, NodeJS and react

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/cloud-native/logging-with-elastic-stack